# "All the good people" vs. "all of the good people"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, determiners, all-of, partitives

I've heard both of these before.

> - All the good people
> - All of the good people

Are they both correct?

Comment: Related: [difference between 'all' and 'all the'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4863/).

Comment: And possible duplicate of [Is it correct to use “all this” instead of “all of this”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4906/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both correct! They both have the same meaning. The "of" variant is a partitive genitive, like French *bouteille de vin* (bottle of wine). I'd say "all of" has a connotation of "all members of group x", whereas "all" without "of" is completely neutral, just the entirety of x. In most cases either connotation will result in the exact same meaning.

Comment: @Jasper Loy: Thanks! The exclamation mark was probably due to drink, but I 'll give you another one despite my hangover!