# All of these VS All These

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality

F*** all these b****
F*** all of these b****

Which one is correct?
And why ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any difference in meaning between "All these" and "All of these"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92701/is-there-any-difference-in-meaning-between-all-these-and-all-of-these)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to use "all this" instead of "all of this"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4906/is-it-correct-to-use-all-this-instead-of-all-of-this)

Comment: Now I'm stuck trying to think of a rude word, starting with 'b', with five letters as a plural.